# why only viewWillAppear called on navigation back

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I have doubt need to be clear.. I have stack and a navigation controller.now when the stack loads the `viewDidLoad` `viewWillAppear` `viewDidAppear` will be called. when i click some button then this button push me to the new stack , now new stack gives me the option of the back..now when i click on the back of the navigation controller..why only `viewWillAppear` will be called ..why not `viewDidLoad` and not `viewDidAppear`

Comment: viewDidAppear must be called. Try putting NSLog instead if you are checking with breakpoint

Comment: `viewDidAppear` always gets called in my apps. Make sure that in your `viewWillAppear:` method that you call `[super viewWillAppear:animated]`. Call the proper `[super xxx]` in your other methods too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Stack is Last In First Out (LIFO), so when you push new view controllers to the stack, previous viewcontroller will not get destroyed( and they remain in memory). When you pop back, there is no need to recreate the Viewcontroller since it is already in memory. So only `viewWillAppear` gets called.

As to why `viewDidAppear` doesn't get called in this case, I cant remember where I have read this, but `viewDidAppear` gets called after your UIViewController's view was added to the application's UIWindow heirarchy. And this process is done before the UIViewController is shown for the first time.

`viewDidLoad` only called when viewControllers views are loaded into the memory. It will be done when

1. the first time the view is needed to be shown
2. sometimes when viewController needed to be reloaded again, because
   it is purged from memory for some low memory reason.

In your case, when you pop back, the viewController is already loaded, so no need to call `viewDidLoad` again.

Comment: yaa ok I got it ...but why not `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLoad`

Comment: ok then in ur case ..`viewWillAppear` and `ViewDidAppear ` should be called ryt...but `viewWillAppear` called only not `ViewDidAppear `

Comment: When a ViewController's view gets added to UIWindow, `viewDidAppear` gets called. When you push new viewController on top of it, the previous one doesn't get removed from UIWindow. So when you pop back, the controller is still in UIWindow hierarchy, so no need to re add it to UIWindow again. Therefore `viewDidAppear` won't get called

Answer (score 13):

Full life cycle of ios ui explain here.[image]

http://www.verydemo.com/demo_c134_i4568.html

Note By [Abizern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41116/abizern) from comment: this is true for iOS5 and earlier. iOS6 does not unload views anymore.

Comment: Add reference from where you got this screenshot :)

Comment: ya but didnt get the logic y only `viewWillAppear`  will get called on navigation back ...not other

Comment: Because when you back that view controller already created. viewDidLoad called in initializing moment only if that already created it not fire. ViewWillAppear call every time it come to screen.

Comment: Difference between didappear and willappear is willappear called befor the event and didappear called after event(when it done).

Comment: Sorry, but how did this answers the question?

Comment: Note - this is true for iOS5 and earlier. iOS6 does not unload views anymore.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, nice question @user2102546. Checkout here the perfect reason for your query.

viewDidLoad only gets called if view controller's views were unloaded, and need to be reloaded.

Normally, if you use a navigation controller, and go back to a previous view with one of the pop methods, **`viewDidLoad does not get called again, because the view are not unloaded yet`**.

However, the system can unload the views of any view controller when it is not frontmost in order to free up memory, so viewDidLoad can get called any time a view controller is about to be presented. You need to write your code to respond correctly to the different events.

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: if we consider the above image by Hasintha and ur answer ...`viewDidLoad does not get called again, because the view are not unloaded yet.` fine the ..`viewdidload will not be called as not unloaded but viewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear both should be called `

Comment: @Christien, Yes, Both viewWillAppear & ViewDidAppear, will be called on navigation back.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a complete answer for you but I hope this helps.

viewDidLoad is a callback for modifying a view after the load event has happened. In your case, the view has already loaded. The fact that it is not in view doesn't mean it has been unloaded from memory.

viewDidAppear: While I don't know why this event isn't firing and would be happy if someone else would fill in the gap.